# replacing an iframe formular with own formular

Tags: php, html, forms, iframe

My problem:
I have an iframe from my partner

```
<iframe src="http://foo.com/aff_c?offer_id=28&aff_id=1020&file_id=164&url_id=32"></iframe>
```

It´s the formular that I have on my page so that visitors can send data. Now I want to create my own formular (to have more control about sent data) and then send data to my partner. At first, I tried to add URL from iframe to 'action' attribute of my form and send it via POST method but then I found out that the original formular is not exactly on URL from iframe, but on another one , where is redirected just after the iframe is loaded, an so it didn´t work. The redirected URL is similar, but with little differences in parametres, something like this:

```
http://blabla.foo2.com/bla?a_aid=1020&a_bid=164&utm_source=affil&offer_id=28
```

So I changed an 'action' attribute of my form with this second URL and now I am sending data right there. It works now, data are sent but there is the problem. The other side (my partner) cannot identify if data comes from me or from another partner. Apparently there is missing parameter in second URL (url_id=32) but I don´t know how to send it.
I was supposed to try php cUrl library but I'm not sure if it could help here.

Ou...and I wouldn't want my partner to know that I am not using his iframe so I can't ask him for help :)

Is there any way in php, how to solve it? Thank you for any idea

Comment: Add the variables as hidden fields in your form, put your form action to `http://blabla.foo2.com/bla`, and post your form, see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the tracking is done in the first script/url and then the data is send to the second url. Maybe you can trigger tracking with first url and cUrl and then send everything to the second url.

To get the last url with curl try:

```
$lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
echo $lastUrl;
```

see also: http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: Yes, you´re right, I missed tracking. It should work your way. But is there way (maybe some option in cUrl) to trigger url without redirecting to it?